# SQL Updating all mistyped entries on the same table while performing a query

Tags: php, sql, insert

A little help guys, I have table named products with the following fields

```
[Products]
pid
name
category
```

Problem is there are lots of erroneous entries under the category which refers to the same category.

Example of Erroneous Categories:

```
Bags and wallet
Bags and Wallets
Bag and Walles
Bags & Wallets
```

Correct One should be Bags & Wallets

I want to change everything using a single SQL statement with a subquery

```
UPDATE products
SET category = 'BAGS & WALLETS'
FROM products 
WHERE category = (select category from products WHERE category like 'BAGS AND WALL')
```

Comment: This is why you should normalise your database... you need a separate table called "categories", which has fields "category_id" and "description", and the category in your main table should have the id of the categories table, not the description. In this way, the description exists only once, and so it is always coherent.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement MySQL's `REGEXP` searching:

```
UPDATE products
SET category = 'BAGS & WALLETS'
FROM products 
WHERE category REGEXP 'BAGS? AND WALL'
```

Answer (score -1):

Look how the `LIKE` clause is working with the wildcard character `%`:

```
UPDATE products
SET category = 'BAGS & WALLETS'
WHERE UPPER(category) LIKE 'BAGS AND WALL%'
```